# creating views count of a perticular articule with request.remote_ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app which has an story model and a views_count model. when a user enters a stories show page it increments the stories view count by 1. From what i have do the story fails to increment from my code below

Stories controller

```
  def show
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    @story.viewed!(request.remote_ip)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @story }
    end
  end
```

story model

```
  def viewed!(ip)
    view_count_id = "#{self.id}-#{ip}"
    if ViewsCount.where({:id => view_count_id}).first.nil?
      ViewsCount.create(:id => view_count_id)
      self.views_count += 1
    end
  end
```

i cant increment the stories views_count.

The approch i took prevents the user from holding down the reload button to keep incrementing the counter. pls any better approach to this or what am i getting wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with the [impressionist](http://rubygems.org/gems/impressionist) gem